# MySql format number with space as thousand delimiter and no decimal zeros

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Having the number: `103,648.340` format it to be as the expected result

Expect result: 103 648.34

My progress:

```sql
SELECT
    TRIM(price)+0 as price_without_decimal_zeros,
    FORMAT(price, 1, 'bg_BG') as thousand_delimited_by_space
from products
```

1. `TRIM` remove decimal zeros, so I've `103,648.34`
2. `FORMAT` add thousand delimited by space, so I've `103 648.340`

I've tried to combine `TRIM` with `FORMAT` without success

Comment: ```SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM FORMAT(price, 3, 'bg_BG'))```. PS. Integer value will look like `'123 456.'`

Comment: @Akina if number is `123`, it will be `123,`

Comment: If so then add one more TRIM which removes final dot if present. Or use according REGEX instead of both TRIMs. Moreover, you may use single REGEX_REPLACE() for formatting.

Comment: Hello @VasileRadeanu what do you wish to get if the number in your database is 123? Thanks!

Comment: @VBoka just `123`

Comment: Hello @VasileRadeanu and what type of data is your column price in your table?

Comment: @VBoka `decimal(15,4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '0' from REPLACE(format(price, 3), ",", " ") )) AS price
FROM products
WHERE price LIKE '%.%'
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5540d973b174619bd9805d42ca28d4d8)